# ODE - Help finding a mistake

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, solution-verification

As is said in the question I'm working on an Ordinary Diferrential Equation problem in which I'm pretty sure I have a mistake but I don't know where.. I hope someone can help me with this!

The problem is the following:

I want to integrate the equation, $F(x,\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}):= \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} - (\frac{1}{2x} + \frac{1}{x+ 1})(\frac{dx}{dt})^2= 0$ by an integrating factor $λ = (\frac{dx}{dt})^{-1}$. Namely, I need to find a function $G(x,\frac{dx}{dt})$ such that $\frac{dG}{dt} = (\frac{dx}{dt})^{−1}F(x,\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{d^2x}{dt^2})$.

First I basically computed $λF$:

$$(\frac{dx}{dt})^{−1}(\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}) - (\frac{1}{2x} + \frac{1}{x+ 1})(\frac{dx}{dt}) = \frac{dG}{dt}$$

And reducing we obtain:

$$\frac{x"}{x'} - (\frac{1}{2x} + \frac{1}{x+ 1})x' = \frac{dG}{dt}$$

Where, (since $x$ depends only on $t$): $x' = \frac{dx}{dt}$ and $x" = \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$. Then I thought to use a separation of variables as follows:

$$\int\frac{x"}{(x')^2}dt - \int(\frac{1}{2x} + \frac{1}{x+ 1})dt = \int\frac{1}{x'}dGdt$$

However I am bit lost because I observed that integrating $x$ relatively to $x$ or $t$ gives same result.. so I really think I did something wrong before because computing this integral is, first, not that easy, and second, not usefull to find G.

Also, I was given a hint but I never found out how to use it, it was:$\frac{d}{dt}\log(g(x)) = \frac{g′(x)}{g(x)}\frac{dx}{dt}$, and $\frac{d}{dt}\log(h(\frac{dx}{dt})) = \frac{h′(x′)}{h(x′)}\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}.$

Comment: I didn't think of this indeed, but since my point is to find G I should rather solve $\frac{dx'}'dx}x' - f(x)(x')^2 = \frac{dG}{dt}, shouldn't I? Doing so I obtain:

$G = \log(x') - \frac{1}{2}\log(x) - \log(x + 1) + C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{x"}{x'} - (\frac{1}{2x} + \frac{1}{x+ 1})x' = \frac{dG}{dt}=0$$
$$\frac{\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}}{\frac{dx}{dt}} - (\frac{1}{2x} + \frac{1}{x+ 1})\frac{dx}{dt} =0$$
$\frac{\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\ln\left|\frac{dx}{dt}\right| \right)$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\ln\left|\frac{dx}{dt}\right| \right) - (\frac{1}{2x} + \frac{1}{x+ 1})\frac{dx}{dt} =0$$
Integrate wrt $t$ :
$$\ln\left|\frac{dx}{dt}\right| - \left(\frac{1}{2}\ln|x|+ \ln|x+ 1|\right) =c_1$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\pm e^{c_1}|x|^{1/2}(x+1)$$
This ODE is separable. I suppose that you can take it from here.

Comment: Indeed I didn't use the fact that $\frac{\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}}{\frac{dx}{dt}} = \frac{d}{dt}(\ln|\frac{dx}{dt}|)$ at this moment, and in the end I achieve a reasonable result, so thank you @JJacquelin